# How to publish HP Fortify Result to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, fortify

We would like to store HP Fortify PDF scan reports to AWS S3 bucket - If someone can help - is there any way to extract the result and store it in AWS that would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to create a PDF report of scan results. Two require human interaction, one can be automated.

Human interaction: Both Audit Workbench and SSC have a "Reports" option in the menu at the top. Select it, select PDF report.

Automated: In /bin there's a ReportGenerator utility, it's a command-line version of the Audit Workbench reports. Run "ReportGenerator -h" for more info, or in your PDF docs there should be one for Utilities that covers this too.